# openpyxl read-only mode cannot iter_cols

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a large excel file that I want to iterate over its columns. Since it is a large excel file, I should use the read-only mode in openpyxl and `iter_cols` is not available in this mode. How can I rewrite this code without using `iter_cols`? Here is my code:

```
def CheckTag(min_col, max_col):
    for col_cells in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=min_col, max_col=max_col):
        for cell in col_cells:
            cell_obj_str = str(cell)
            if (cell.value in tags or cell_obj_str[-2:] == "1>"):
                print("PASS", cell_obj_str[-2:])
            else:
                cell_obj_str = str(cell)
                errors_file.write(cell_obj_str + "Tag is Wrong\r\n")
```

Comment: You can't: cells are stored in XLSX files by rows and this is the only way to read them in read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it to direct cell accessing:

```py
def CheckTag(min_col, max_col):
    for col in range(min_col, max_col+1):
        for row in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
            cell = sheet.cell(col, row)
            ...  # rest of code stays the same
```

Comment: It'll check cells horizontally. I want to check rows per column for example check all the tags in Tag column.

Comment: That does exactly the same as your original code: loops all rows of all columns

Comment: There are different conditions in every column. I want to check them separately per column.

Comment: min_col and max_col are always the same

Comment: OK so? I don't see the problem. My code is equivalent to yours...

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the problem @fzsdi ?

Comment: Couldn't make it work with "openpyxl", changed the library to "xlrd" and it is working properly.

Comment: @CharlieClark How would you do it? What would be good-practice?

Comment: In read-only mode you want to limit calls to **any** kind of cell lookup because this forces the library to reparse the source file.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks for the info, didn't know that! How would you say is best to do what OP is trying? Or it simply can't be achieved optimally (searching rows by columns)?